# Chaning the SQL column name

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have two tables:

Table1

```
ID Name  Col1 Col2 Col3
------------------------
1   aaaa  a    b    c
2   bbb   d    e    f
```

Tabl2 -- Lookup Table

```
Column  Desc
-------------
Col1    2011
Col2    2012
```

I would like to write SQL such that, I wan to modify column alias when it finds matching column in other table.
The output should come as below. I want the column names should be changed if there is reference name found in table2

```
ID  Name 2011 2012 Col3
------------------------
1   aaaa   a    b   c
2   bbb    d    e   f
```

Comment: Any particular query always produces a result set with a fixed "shape" - the number of columns, their *names* and types. You'd have to use dynamic SQL or, usually better in my opinion, perform the renaming up at the presentation layer (application, report builder, etc - whatever is *consuming* this result set).

Comment: Why do the cosmetic at the back end? Isn't this supposedly handled at the front end GUI?

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/what-have-you-tried/)

Answer (score 0):

You can create a dynamic sql query for this.

Match the `column_name` from `table1` with the `Desc` column in `table2`.

**Query**

```
declare @sql as varchar(max);

set @sql = 'select ' + stuff((select ',' + t.c1 + ' as [' + coalesce(t.c2, t.c1) + ']'
            from (
                select t1.Column_name as c1, t2.[Desc] as c2
                from information_schema.columns t1
                left join table2 t2
                on t1.column_name = t2.[column]
                where t1.table_name = 'table1'
            )t
            for xml path('')
        ), 1, 1, '');

select @sql+= ' from table1;';

exec(@sql);
```